# Using Where statement on comma seperated value in sqlite

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have sqlite database with table containing comma seperated fields like that:

Data Field containing:

```
Frank; 34 California street; 0123456789
```

FieldData Field containing:

```
Name; Address; Phone number
```

I want to make where query on only one data. For example:

```
Select * From Persons Where Name = 'Frank';
```

Please help!

Comment: Fix your data model.  These values should be stored in separate columns.  Not in strings.

Comment: I agree that you should fix your datamodel. but if you can't you can consider this : substr(field,1,instr(field,';')-1)

Comment: I can't fix data model because the data columns are dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but your model performance will be very bad! if you have to you can do something like this :

```
  Select * From Persons Where substr(field,1,instr(field,';')-1) = 'Frank';
```

Comment: What about other data for example address?

Comment: Why don't you bring the data then filter them in your code ?

Comment: Because the user makes the query in recursive GUI

Comment: Even you can filter the data from code. why don't you consider adding columns and removing them from code to implement dynamic columns. because I think in your approach you're going to mismatch the column on every row by adding and removing the columns